# update table using where exists

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

in my program i try to update store table

[image: pictur1]

values according to storetemp table but it changes all value to last value in stortemp

[image: picture2]

this is my code

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute ("UPDATE store, storetemp " & _
"SET store.[cuantity]=storetemp.[cuantity] " & _
"WHERE EXISTS ( " & _
"SELECT 1 FROM storetemp " & _
"WHERE store.[name] = storetemp.[name] " & _
") ")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You haven't shown the definition of your table(s), without which it's hard to give a good answer.  See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afraid I can't see the images.

Try joining your table rather than using exists:

```
UPDATE          Store INNER JOIN StoreTemp ON Store.[Name] = StoreTemp.[Name]
SET             Store.Cuantity = StoreTemp.Cuantity
```